# Volume of submanifold as integral of delta-function

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, integration, embeddings, metric-embeddings

Let $M$ be an $n-m$ dimensional sub-manifold of $\mathbf R^n$ defined by the following set of equations:
\begin{equation}
f_1(\vec x)=0, \\
\vdots \\
f_m(\vec x)=0,
\end{equation}
(where $\vec x$ are coordinates in $\mathbf R^n$).
Is it true that the volume of $M$ is
\begin{equation}
\int d^nx\sqrt{\det (JJ^T)}\prod_{i=1}^m\delta(f_i(\vec x))
\end{equation}
where $\delta()$ is the Dirac-Delta and where $J$ is the rectangular matrix $J_{i\mu}\equiv \frac{\partial f_i(\vec x)}{\partial x^\mu}$ with $i=1,...,m$ and $\mu=1,...,n$?

Comment: What if we only have one $f_1 = x_1$ but $n$ is big? It looks like $\det(JJ^T) = 0$ so the whole integral is $0$.

Comment: @VladimirZolotov No $\det(J J^T)=1$ because $(J J^T)_{ij}=\sum_\mu J_{i\mu}J_{j\mu}$ and $J_{i\mu}\equiv J_{1\mu}=\delta_{1\mu}$.

Comment: That integral does  not transform appropriately.  If you scale $f$, the integral changes, but the volume of the manifold does not.

Comment: @RyanBudney Actually I don't think that's true. If each $f_i$ is scaled by a constant $k_i$, then $\prod_i \delta(f_i)\to \prod_i \frac{\delta(f_i)}{|k_i|}$ and $\det(JJ^T)\to\det(JJ^T)\prod_i k_i^2$ such that all $k_i$ cancel.

Comment: What is your definition of "volume" of the manifold $M$?   I think if you are taking the induced Riemann metric from being a submanifold of Euclidean space, this integral won't agree.  Your integral  it something like the dual of the Thom class, so you have a normalization problem.

Answer (score 4):

One should distinguish between the *volume* of the submanifold (a number that might be infinite) and  the *volume form*, an exterior differential form $\omega$ of degree $n{-}m$ on the (presumed regular) 0 level set $M = f^{-1}(0)\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ of the mapping $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$.

The formula for $\omega$ is easy to write down:  If $f = (f^1,\ldots,f^m)$ and we set $J^{ij} = J^{ji} =  \nabla f^i\cdot\nabla f^j$, then
$$
\omega(v_1,\ldots,v_{n-m}) 
= \frac{\Omega(\nabla f^1,\ldots,\nabla f^m,v_1,\ldots,v_{n-m})}{\det(J)^{1/2}},
$$
where $\Omega = \mathrm{d}x^1\wedge\cdots\wedge\mathrm{d}x^n$ is the volume form on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Regularity is equivalent to the condition that $\det(J)$ be nonvanishing on $M=f^{-1}(0)$. This assumes, of course, that $M$ is given the orientation for which $\omega$ is a positive $n{-}m$ form.

For example, when $n=2$ and $m=1$, one finds that
$$
\omega = \frac{f_x\,\mathrm{d}y-f_y\,\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{{f_x}^2+{f_y}^2}}\,.
$$
There is, of course, no explicit formula for $\int_M\omega$ in terms of $f$, even when $f$ is a polynomial.